# Walk forward validation problem when looping

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am trying to code a walk forward validation for a classification algorithm, but I can't figure out why the loop is not appending the blind data. Any comment/suggestion will be highly appreciate it.

```
X = data.values
n_train = 500
n_records = len(X)
for i in range(n_train, n_records):
    probsL = []
    probsS = []
    cls = MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()).fit(X[:,0:21][0:i], X[:,21:42][0:i])
    predict_prob = cls.predict_proba(X[:,0:21][i:i+1])
    p_prob = np.concatenate([col[:,[2]] for col in predict_prob], 1)
    n_prob = np.concatenate([col[:,[0]] for col in predict_prob], 1)
    probsL.append(p_prob)
    probsS.append(n_prob)
```

Comment: You're declaring empty lists at the start of each run of the loop, then appending to the list, then redeclaring it as empty when the loop starts again. Did you mean to have the `probsL` and `probsS` lists outside the loop?

Comment: OMG Right. Thank you so much. No I didn't, that's the mistake. Solved.